# Is there a Magic intro deck that focuses on lifestealing?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I just started playing Magic using the Android app, and I really like it.  Now I would like to start playing Magic with real cards as well. In the Android app I chose the deck that focuses on stealing enemy life,  and adding it to your own.  Is there any pre-made intro deck for this play style?

Comment: Be careful when deciding on what to do with these answers (if you haven't already) - Depending on who you play magic with and where, you might find that the recommendations based on your preference don't work for you for unexpected reasons. If you were looking to play at a local Friday Night Magic in a store for example, Return To Ravnica cards are not standard legal, which might be a problem for you.

I refer you to this question which might provide some useful tips: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-much-would-it-cost-to-get-started-with-magic-the-gathering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the clearest "life stealing" mechanics is [Extort](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Extort), which is a triggered ability permanents have that says

> Whenever you cast a spell, you may pay {W/B}. If you do, each opponent loses 1 life and you gain life equal to the total life lost this way.

Extort is from the Return to Ravnica block, and there were two intro packs built around it and related mechanics: [Orzhov Oppression](https://web.archive.org/web/20150927110702/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/tcg/productarticle.aspx?x=mtg/tcg/gatecrash/intropacks#deck1) from Gatecrash and [Orzhov Power](https://web.archive.org/web/20150927110413/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/tcg/productarticle.aspx?x=mtg/tcg/dragonsmaze/intropacks#deck2) from Dragon's Maze.

Comment: For what it's worth, of the two of those, Power looks more fun & flavorful.

Comment: In general, White-Black decks are really the only way to steal life.  The have extort and lifelink.